# Why can't I use asynchronous functions when calling remote objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I constructed a remote object that contains an asynchronous function that throws an exception when the client calls it.

Exception information:

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version" in the assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" =4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]” is not marked as serializable.”

```
[Serializable]
public class ClassA
{
    public String Str = "Hello World";
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class DataObj : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public ClassA A = new ClassA();

    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }


    public async Task<bool> DoSth()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        Console.WriteLine("aaa");

        return false;
    }
}
```

```
public class Server
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        HttpServerChannel channel = new HttpServerChannel("A",10000);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(DataObj), "DataObj", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

```
class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClientChannel channel = new HttpClientChannel();
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
        DataObj obj = (DataObj)Activator.GetObject(typeof(DataObj), @"http://127.0.0.1:10000/DataObj");

        //An exception is thrown when the client calls
        obj.DoSth();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose "because tasks aren't serializable" is too ... unhelpful? but really: that's it - there's a lot of plumbing involved in tasks, and : it isn't well suited to remoting, as a: it involves multiple calls (chatty APIs are bad for remoting), and b: it involves delegates, which aren't good for remoting... so: nobody has ever considered it being worth doing all the work to make this work? also: remoting is kinda out of fashion and very rarely used these days

Comment: Figure this out yourself.  It is the only way to learn.See what is being returned from following : var obj = Activator.GetObject(typeof(DataObj), @"http://127.0.0.1:10000/DataObj");

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok, thank you for solving my doubts.

Comment: @jdweng a proxy to a remote `MarshalByRefObject` type... I don't see how that makes anything obvious...

Comment: @MarcGravell What do you mean by remoting being out of fashion ? Are you refering to how people use cloud services nowadays ?

Comment: @OlivierSamson I didn't mention cloud *at all* - but: .NET remoting simply isn't a popular technology choice and hasn't been for many many years; it *started* to ebb around the time of WCF, which was (checks calendar) 2006 - and *for most purposes* has been replaced with things like HTTP (simple json or xml), or things like gRPC or micro-service frameworks. None of these things require "cloud", although all of them would *work* on "cloud" servers. Fortunately for all of us: SOAP is also much reduced from what it was.